# How to test IMAP operations with phpunit?

Tags: mocking, phpunit, imap

I'm new to testing and working on a system (written in PHP) which fetches e-mails from an IMAP server, investigates the messages and then moves them to different mailboxes, depending on their contents.

I haven't decided on any IMAP library yet. What is the best approach regarding automated unit tests?

A) Should I mock all necessary objects to test the automation process without any real server? If all objects are mocked, and I want to test a mailbox object for instance if a message was moved - then I have just a mocked object which provides no functionality to move a message. Is it correct to implement some functionality to move the message in the mock object? It somehow feels like I'd write a lot of code and not testing any relevant logic at all because the mocked objects might behave different than the real thing.

B) Should I use a real IMAP server which holds some test messages? But then I would have to reset it to the original state after each test. And if someday someone touches the real mailbox, all unit tests may break.

Thanks for your ideas and help. :)

Additional information: it would be fine to use a third party software / programming language to simulate an IMAP server as long as it provides the same API like a real IMAP system. Only the business logic has to be in PHP.

Comment: With the conventional php_imap IMAP library, it's pretty much impossible to mock out because it's so monolithic, and based on a C library.  If it's an option, there are, I believe, much better libraries in other languages with way better control and options.  If you're stuck with PHP, you'll be left with a lot of shortcomings.  There may be other libraries to check.

This question does seem to be a bit offtopic for stackoverflow though.  This is more of a software engineering design problem, which really pushes the boundaries of the scope of the site.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your comment. I looked into the [Horde IMAP client](https://dev.horde.org/imap_client/), [ddeboer/imap](https://github.com/ddeboer/imap), [barbushin/php-imap](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) and [ssilence/php-imap-client](https://github.com/SSilence/php-imap-client).
Using a real server will eventually slow down the whole test suite, right? I thought I could somehow treat the IMAP server like a database. Yes, I'm pretty much stuck with PHP. Do you know a better place for this question?

Comment: I have to add: it would be fine to use a third party software / programming language to simulate an IMAP server. Only the business logic has to be in PHP.

Comment: For now I think I'll probably mock out the messages and then use spies to verify the php application triggers the right commands and rely on the IMAP library and Server to do what they have to do.

Comment: Before looking `class & methods` really hard to say the way of `PhpUnitTest` but In my opinion instead of mocking you use `Real Servers` because by this way you will test the real working and in `unittesting` most of the function have two parameters like `expected` and `actual` so retrieve the `mail object` form server and store it in `actual` variable and then after moving the email again retrieve the mail and store it in `expected` and by this way you can perform test.        rest is all depends on your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that using a real server is just way too slow. So I used mocked objects and isolated the components under test in a way that I only have to provide a `Message` object and then observe the internal state of the system with spies. So each test has a very specific scope and it's more of an unit than an integration test.

I used real e-mails and saved them on disk in `.eml` files, I wrote an utility which builds a mocked object out of that. Most imap libraries I looked into require a connection to a real server to retrieve data and build a message object. So this part is a little ugly, because it retrieves the message data completely different than the library does.

On the other hand, handling the communication with an IMAP server is what the library is developed and tested for, so if there are no breaking changes in its public interfaces, this should be fine.

I also decided the communication with the imap server should be part of manual smoke and integration tests only, there's no need to include that in automated tests.

It might also be possible to use a stream wrapper which imitates an IMAP server.

Answer (score 0):

I use greenmail for my integration tests.

> It is an open source, intuitive and easy-to-use test suite of email
>   servers for testing purposes

http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/